# Why is the direction of E field inside a Linear Dielectric same as an external field?

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric

If an uncharged linear dielectric is exposed in a uniform external field, an e field inside is induced that points in the same direction as the External field, Why is this so?

Isnt the field be oppossite since negative charge accumulates in the direction of the source external field?